# C++ why is this destructor called and where does it come from

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor

I'm learning about desctructors, copy and clone and therefor I wrote this code. Everything is clear to me but one line. It is the destructor in line 5 `Destructor myClass1 0x28fec0`. Where does it come from and why is it called?

Console output:

```
Constructor myClass1 0x28fe98
Constructor myClass2 0x28fe88
Constructor myClass3 0x28fe78
operator=
Destructor myClass1 0x28fec0
clone
Constructor clone 0x28fed0
operator=
Destructor clone 0x28fed0
Destructor myClass3 0x28fe78
Destructor myClass2 0x28fe88
Destructor myClass1 0x28fe98
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(){
    MyClass myClass1("myClass1"), myClass2("myClass2"), myClass3("myClass3");
    myClass2 = myClass1;
    myClass3 = myClass1.clone();
    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass{
private:
    int *values;
    int size;
    int *copies;
    std::string name;
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(std::string name);
    ~MyClass();
    void operator=(MyClass myClass);
    MyClass clone();
};

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(){
    std::cout << "Constructor" << this << std::endl;
    name = "None";
    size = 1;
    values = new int[1];
    values[0] = 0;
    copies = new int;
    *copies = 1;
    count++;
}

MyClass::MyClass(std::string name){
    std::cout << "Constructor " << name << " " << this << std::endl;
    size = 1;
    values = new int[1];
    values[0] = 0;
    copies = new int;
    *copies = 1;
    count++;
    this->name = name;
}

MyClass::~MyClass(){
    std::cout << "Destructor " << name << " " << this << std::endl;
    if(*copies == 1){
        delete [] values;
        values = 0;
        delete copies;
        copies = 0;
    }
    count--;
}

void MyClass::operator=(MyClass myClass){
    std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl;
    if(*copies == 1){
        delete copies;
        copies = 0;
        delete [] values;
        values = 0;
    }
    size = myClass.size;
    values = myClass.values;
    copies = myClass.copies;
    (*copies)++;
}

MyClass MyClass::clone(){
    std::cout << "clone" << std::endl;
    MyClass myClass("clone");
    myClass.size = size;
    delete [] myClass.values;

    myClass.values = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myClass.values[i] = values[i];
    }
    return myClass;
}
```

Comment: Nice program that clearly attempts to demonstrate the question you're asking. If possible though, please use your editor and browser's copy and paste functionality after making sure your program works. You have some omissions and typos.

Comment: Thank you, for all answers. It's correct. After implementing a copy constructor, I can see the construction and destruction in the operator=.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're taking the argument to `operator=` as a copy.

So it creates a `MyClass` object inside `operator=`, which gets destroyed when `operator=` returns.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: The compiler is generating a default copy constructor, which doesn't have `cout` in it.

Answer (score 3):

`void MyClass::operator=(MyClass myClass)` takes its argument by value. So, when you call

`myClass2 = myClass1;`

the copy constructor creates a copy of `myClass1` into the `MyClass` argument of `MyClass::operator=`. When that function finishes, this copy is destroyed. To see this happening, put print statements in the copy constructor `MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)`.

Also, quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), the canonical overload of the assignment operator for a type `T` is

```
T& T::operator=(T arg) { // copy/move constructor is called to construct arg
    swap(arg);    // resources exchanged between *this and arg
    return *this;
}  // destructor is called to release the resources formerly held by *this
```

This is the copy-and-swap idiom. Also note that the return type is `T&` and not `void`.

Answer (score 1):

`void operator=(MyClass myClass);` should be `MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& myClass);` (standard). Else, you pass myClass by copy, meaning that a temporary object is created....and then destroyed.